# iOS - How to allow user to select from a range of numbers?

Tags: ios, user-interface

What's the besy way to allow a user to select a number on iOS? Basically I have a "form" that allows users to set up a game. One of the options requires them to specify the number of teams.

My first idea was to use a slider, but how would I lay this out? The following doesn't seem very intuitive:

```
Select number of teams: 5
C=====O=================D
```

But then again, this doesn't look very good either:

```
Select number of teams:
C========O==========D 5
```

My second idea was to create a button that when pressed, shows the user a modal view with a UIPickerview but then this seems a bit over the top just to select a number.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have only few choices to select from you might want to use a few buttons with one selected showing different color (and text would indicate value of selection).

Also alternative is to have two buttons +/- and text box which would increment and decrement number of teams.

And finally you can use one of the custom controls:

- http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/iphone-development/custom-dropdown-list/
- http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/cdpiemenu

Answer (score 1):

Both methods are fine. A slider works well, if you don't have a exhausting range of numbers to select from, since that *could* make the slider a little unprecise. I'd go for your second layout and put the number next to the slider and the label above.

However, a slider can only select *one* number - in your question title you are referring to "select a *range* of numbers". That is quite a difference. If you need a slider to select a range (like 3 to 5), a [two-way slider](http://buildmobile.com/wicked-ios-range-slider-part-one) custom component would be necessary.

Comment: Ah yes. I've just mocked it up and it doesn't look as back as I first thought. And you're right about my question wording! I meant to say select FROM a range of numbers... as in there's a min and a max. Thanks again.